# Limit when $x$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, fractions

Can someone please help me with this simple limit problem, I do not know what to do here because its undefined $0/0$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{1/x}}{\sqrt{x}}.$$

Comment: $e^{1/x} \rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ from the right, maybe you meant $e^{-1/x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\sqrt{x}e^{x}=+\infty$$

Comment: But what did we do here, I am afraid I don't understand... how does X converge to $∞$ now ?

Comment: If $x\rightarrow0^+$ then $\frac{1}{x}\rightarrow+\infty$. Also, If $x\rightarrow+\infty$ then $\sqrt{x}\rightarrow+\infty$ and $e^x\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I understand now

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{1/x}}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{\lim_{x\to0} e^{1/x}}{\lim_{x\to0} \sqrt{x}} = \frac{\infty}{0} = \infty$$